# secure nodejs production environment that use dotenv

Tags: node.js, hashicorp-vault, dotenv

By using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) I can ignore development .env file before pushing it to the git repository, it comply with [The Twelve-Factor App config factor](https://12factor.net/config). It prevent configuration from exposing to others especially open source project.

But I am stuck when deploying it to the production, either using cloud deployment or using docker.

How can I include this file? Should I save the file into [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) or something?

Please help me to understand how can I secure my deployment environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  The server environment (docker or otherwise) needs to be configured with its own environment variables, not the development ones.   Any that will be the same in both you configure as default values for the application so that they have that value even if the variable isn't set.

Comment: But is that considered secure? Just having your authentication/authorization credentials saved as environmental variables on the server?

Comment: @aerovistae that depends on a whole lot of other factors, like how you’re building the machine and so on.  In general, yes if you lock down the machine well enough, use non privileged accounts to act as the service user, etc.  generally in larger deployments you’d actually persist them in a secrets vault and have the system get injected with them at build time from chef, ansible, whatever.  From the application perspective, though, they are still just environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file transfer protocol such as filezilla or cyberduck and transfer the file to your production server environment. Make sure the .env file you send to your server contains the credentials for the production database and not the development one and so on. You could alternatively just add environment variables to your remote server's .env or .bashrc file, but this is probably not advisable compared to a .env file. As long as no one but you has access to the remote server (docker, heroku, aws, etc) your credentials should be secure. Never share your .pem files.